# Trouble updating my datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

As the title indicates, I'm having trouble updating a datagrid in WPF. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is a datagrid, that is connected to a SQL Server database, that updates automatically once a user enters information into a few textboxes and clicks a submit button. You'll notice that I have a command that joins two tables. The data from the Quote_Data table will be inserted by a different user at a later time. For now my only concern is getting the information from the textboxes and into the General_Info table, and from there into my datagrid. The code, which I'll include below compiles fine, but when I hit the submit button, nothing happens. This is the first application I've ever built working with a SQL Database so many of these concepts are new to me, which is why you'll probably look at my code and wonder what is he thinking.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataSet mds; // main data set (mds)

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = Sqtm.Properties.Settings.Default.SqtmDbConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                //Merging tables General_Info and Quote_Data
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT General_Info.Quote_ID, General_Info.Open_Quote, General_Info.Customer_Name,"
                                            + "General_Info.OEM_Name, General_Info.Qty, General_Info.Quote_Num, General_Info.Fab_Drawing_Num, "
                                            + "General_Info.Rfq_Num, General_Info.Rev_Num,  Quote_Data.MOA, Quote_Data.MOQ, "
                                            + "Quote_Data.Markup, Quote_Data.FOB, Quote_Data.Shipping_Method, Quote_Data.Freight, "
                                            + "Quote_Data.Vendor_Price, Unit_Price, Quote_Data.Difference, Quote_Data.Vendor_NRE_ET, "
                                            + "Quote_Data.NRE, Quote_Data.ET, Quote_Data.STI_NET, Quote_Data.Mfg_Time, Quote_Data.Delivery_Time, "
                                            + "Quote_Data.Mfg_Name, Quote_Data.Mfg_Location "
                                            + "FROM General_Info INNER JOIN dbo.Quote_Data ON General_Info.Quote_ID = Quote_Data.Quote_ID",
                                            connection);

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                da.Fill(dt);

                MainGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

                mds = new DataSet();

                da.Fill(mds, "General_Info");

                MainGrid.DataContext = mds.Tables["General_Info"];
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        // renaming column names from the database so they are easier to read in the datagrid

        MainGrid.Columns[0].Header = "#";
        MainGrid.Columns[1].Header = "Date";
        MainGrid.Columns[2].Header = "Customer";
        MainGrid.Columns[3].Header = "OEM";
        MainGrid.Columns[4].Header = "Qty";
        MainGrid.Columns[5].Header = "Quote Number";
        MainGrid.Columns[6].Header = "Fab Drawing Num";
        MainGrid.Columns[7].Header = "RFQ Number";
        MainGrid.Columns[8].Header = "Rev Number";
        MainGrid.Columns[9].Header = "MOA";
        MainGrid.Columns[10].Header = "MOQ";
        MainGrid.Columns[11].Header = "Markup";
        MainGrid.Columns[12].Header = "FOB";
        MainGrid.Columns[13].Header = "Shipping";
        MainGrid.Columns[14].Header = "Freight";
        MainGrid.Columns[15].Header = "Vendor Price";
        MainGrid.Columns[16].Header = "Unit Price";
        MainGrid.Columns[17].Header = "Difference";
        MainGrid.Columns[18].Header = "Vendor NRE/ET";
        MainGrid.Columns[19].Header = "NRE";
        MainGrid.Columns[20].Header = "ET";
        MainGrid.Columns[21].Header = "STINET";
        MainGrid.Columns[22].Header = "Mfg. Time";
        MainGrid.Columns[23].Header = "Delivery Time";
        MainGrid.Columns[24].Header = "Manufacturer";
        MainGrid.Columns[25].Header = "Mfg. Location";

    }

    private void submitQuotebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerData newQuote = new CustomerData();

        int quantity;
        quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityTxt.Text);

        string theDate = System.DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d");

        newQuote.OpenQuote = theDate;
        newQuote.CustomerName = customerNameTxt.Text;
        newQuote.OEMName = oemNameTxt.Text;
        newQuote.Qty = quantity;
        newQuote.QuoteNumber = quoteNumberTxt.Text;
        newQuote.FdNumber = fabDrawingNumberTxt.Text;
        newQuote.RfqNumber = rfqNumberTxt.Text;
        newQuote.RevNumber = revNumberTxt.Text;

        try
        {
            string insertConString = Sqtm.Properties.Settings.Default.SqtmDbConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection insertConnection = new SqlConnection(insertConString))
            {
                insertConnection.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Sqtm.Properties.Settings.Default.SqtmDbConnectionString, insertConnection);

                SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE General_Info " + "Quote_ID = @Quote_ID, "
                                                    + "Open_Quote = @Open_Quote, " + "OEM_Name = @OEM_Name, " + "Qty = @Qty, "
                                                    + "Quote_Num = @Quote_Num, " + "Fab_Drawing_Num = @Fab_Drawing_Num, "
                                                    + "Rfq_Num = @Rfq_Num, " + "Rev_Num = @Rev_Num "
                                                    + "WHERE Quote_ID = @Quote_ID");

                updateCmd.Connection = insertConnection;

                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection param = updateCmd.Parameters;

                //
                // Add new SqlParameters to the command.
                //
                param.AddWithValue("Open_Quote", newQuote.OpenQuote);
                param.AddWithValue("Customer_Name", newQuote.CustomerName);
                param.AddWithValue("OEM_Name", newQuote.OEMName);
                param.AddWithValue("Qty", newQuote.Qty);
                param.AddWithValue("Quote_Num", newQuote.QuoteNumber);
                param.AddWithValue("Fab_Drawing_Num", newQuote.FdNumber);
                param.AddWithValue("Rfq_Num", newQuote.RfqNumber);
                param.AddWithValue("Rev_Num", newQuote.RevNumber);

                adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;

                adapter.Update(mds.Tables[0]);

                mds.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help, I really appreciate it,

- Andrew

Comment: What means "Nothing happens"? Did you debug it? How far does the code work? Do you get an answer from the server? ...

Comment: Hey DHN, I did debug and from what I can tell everything seems to be working properly. Database connections open when they're supposed to, and while I'm not entirely sure how to check the values in my data tables from SSMS, when I stepped through the code at param.AddWithValue... I was told that the SqlValues for each line was equal to what I had entered in the textbox earlier. I'm hoping that the problem has to do with how I set the datagrid up itself, with data adapters/datatables/and datasets; areas I am still a little confused on.

Comment: I do have another theory as to what could be causing the problem. The way the General_Info data table is set up, its primary key is called Quote_ID and in Sql Server Management Studio, I set it up to automatically be added to a new row and increment by one for the next row. That said, after the submit button is clicked, my code only references the Quote_ID in updateCmd. Do I need to add a param.AddWithValue() for the Quote_ID as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using LINQ I was able to resolve the issue. Here's the code:

```
    var sqtmDC = new SqtmLinqDataContext();

        var mainTable = from generalInfo in sqtmDC.GetTable<General_Info>()
                      //join quoteData in sqtmDataContext.GetTable<Quote_Data>() on generalInfo.Quote_ID equals quoteData.Quote_ID
                      select generalInfo;

                      myGrid.ItemsSource = mainTable;
    }

     private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sqtmDC = new SqtmLinqDataContext();

       // string theDate = System.DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d");
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityTxt.Text);

        General_Info insert = new General_Info();

        insert.Open_Quote = DateTime.UtcNow;
        insert.Customer_Name = customerNameTxt.Text;
        insert.OEM_Name = oemNameTxt.Text;
        insert.Qty = quantity;
        insert.Quote_Num = quoteNumberTxt.Text;
        insert.Fab_Drawing_Num = fabDrawingNumTxt.Text;
        insert.Rfq_Num = rfqNumberTxt.Text;
        insert.Rev_Num = revNumberTxt.Text;

        sqtmDC.General_Infos.InsertOnSubmit(insert);
        sqtmDC.SubmitChanges();

        int quoteID = insert.Quote_ID;

        var mainTable = from generalInfo in sqtmDC.GetTable<General_Info>()

                        select generalInfo;

        myGrid.ItemsSource = mainTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the Quote_ID parameter.  So your update it likely running `WHERE Quote_ID = null` so nothing updates.

Comment: Hey Spevy, thanks for the input, that's kind of where I was thinking the problem was, but I'm not entirely sure how to resolve it, since the Quote_ID is a value that is supposed to be set automatically when a new row is started (i.e. row one is 1000, row two is 10001, etc). How and where should I set the Quote_ID parameter?

Comment: I think you should set the Quote_ID parameter like you set the others, however you need to remove the assignment from your update clause as you don't need to change the value.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly I should change my update clause to:

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. What I meant to say was: So if I'm understanding correctly I should change my update clause to, SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE General_Info " + "Open_Quote = @Open_Quote, " + "..." + "WHERE Quote_ID = @Quote_ID"); and then add param.AddWithValue("Quote_ID", someInt); where someInt is defined earlier as an integer that increments by one each time a new row is started? I'll get started on that and post back. Thanks Spevy

Comment: Im really struggling here and I dont know why. Ive got the primary key's (Quote_ID) Identity set to true with a seed of 1000 and increment of 1. I cant seem to figure out how to link that Quote_ID up with the rest of the table so that it will create a new row in my datagrid. Ive tried creating a second SqlCommand using INSERT INTO for just the Quote_ID but that didnt work. I think what Im confused with the most is how to add the Quote_ID using param.AddWithValues because I think itll work if I write param.AddWithValue("Quote_ID", ???); but I dont know what to replace those question marks with.

Comment: "that did not work" is not good description of what happened. You have a master/details relationship between two tables. You should start by inserting a record into the master table, get its key value back and insert a record into the details table specifying the master key value as a foreign key. Only after that you have a chance of the INNER JOIN to return records.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update an existing row or insert a new row?

Cause if you need to insert then the proper command is insert (not update).
To get the Identity value of the inserted row you use `Scope_Identity()`.

And you can only insert into one table at a time.

`Scope_Identity()` is NOT a param
Do not try and use it as a param

See example below

```
INSERT INTO Sales.Customer ([TerritoryID],[PersonID]) VALUES (8,NULL);
GO
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];
```

There are lots of examples on MSDN.Microsoft.com

Comment: I'm inserting a row, so I should change Update to Insert and below I should write param.AddWithValues("Quote_ID", Quote_ID.Scope_Identity() ); ? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Ignore that previous comment...So I change UPDATE to "INSERT INTO General_Info" + "Quote_ID = @Quote_ID" + "..." + "WHERE Quote_ID = @Quote_ID" correct? Where should I be implementing Scope_Identity()?

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot and post back. Thanks for the help